# Showing Div or Tooltips on mouse hover using pure css

Tags: jquery, css

I have this image, http://imgur.com/FWsgQGE. What I want is, show information about grey areas whenever user hovers over them. I would prefer information to be shown in a div.

Is there a pure CSS way to do that?

Comment: you can slice the image in Photoshop and specify each parts

Comment: so what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use image maps with title attributes to hold the mouseover tooltip. 
Like this:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm" title="sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm" title="mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm" "title="venus">
</map>
```

You can use [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap) to test. Just add the title attributes to the code.

Comment: Then you will need javascript to do that.

Comment: You can look into the jQuery UI for the tooltip examples here: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/